# Monitor a Windows Server using SNMP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, monitoring, snmp

How hard can this be? I want to get the current CPU performance from a remote Win 2k3 machine. I need to use SNMP because the machine is behind a firewall.

Assumptions:

- I understand networking/can configure any kind of IP address/port forwarding/firewall/stuff.
- I understand SNMP - I know how to use my tool to get a value from an OID on a target machine.
- I know what I want to do with the result from my SNMP request.
- I have enabled SNMP on the Windows Server, configured the relevant IP security/community stuff.
- I can already ask the Windows server standard stuff using SNMP about how many disks/network interfaces it has etc.

Question:
- What OID do I used to simply ask current performance usage.

I have spent many hours asking Google - clearly asking the wrong question :S .... How hard can this be?

Answer (score 3):

Use `snmpwalk` to see what the machine is reporting, and pick what looks appropriate :-)

For CPU utilization, the Host Resources MIB provides a SNMP Table at `1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3` which lists each CPU and it's current percent utilization, but these values can be somewhat misleading (100% doesn't always mean your system is overloaded).

[www.oidview.com](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/detail.html) is a good place to go MIB-browsing, and will give you the MIB entity name as well as the OID.

Comment: Hi there. I've done plenty of MIB walking, I'm just surprised there isn't a simple (and standard) summary of CPU utilisation output. Sure, I can query for processors, then walk to get the processor usage for each proc, then add up/average/whatever to get a result that looks nice on the screen - but surely you'd have thought there'd just be one 'CPU utlisation summary' entry... I guess not...

Thanks for your answer!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any OID for 'performance usage', you will need to do your own investigation and determine what you want to capture - a lot of stuff from the HOSTS MIB (CPU, RAM, disk space) are common, but you may also care about specific things that are hardware-specific (vendor-specific RAID card for example.)

What tool are you using? Nagios, OpenNMS, and MRTG have templates for common scenarios.

Also, keep in mind that if you're using SNMP v2, your community strings are cleartext.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your answer. This specifically for a custom built tool, but we do use Nagios as well. Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cacti](http://cacti.net/), on Linux or Windows, to manage snmp data & graph. It will discover oid by itself (using preloaded templates) and generate graphes for you (daily / monthly...)
It's open source

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using getif.exe or a mib browser to see what the machine is exposing.

The oid for generic processor info from one of the RFC mibs is:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1
```

but you'll need to drill in to determine multiprocessor.  On one of my single processor servers the oid is:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.1
```

YMMV.

An excellent source of snmp info is:

http://www.wtcs.org/snmp4tpc/testing.htm

As mentioned elsewhere, once you get the data, MRTG, Cacti, Nagios (et al) are great ways to show historical information, and to get a picture of the server health of your network.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Use `Nagios` which will be installed in a Linux server. It has a lot of plugins built to monitor system performances (CPU/RAM/HDD). Then install `NRPE` on your Windows Server. The `Nagios`/`NRPE` should be started on your windows server. `Nagios` also has a capability of triggering an alarm whenever threshold you have set is reached, and send an email alert to the one who administers the system.

You may also use `Cacti` which also uses `SNMP`. It has plugins to monitor system performances. Compared to `Nagios`, `Cacti` has graphical presentation of current system performance which can update in real time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Nagios` with `Nagios graphs` which give me the opportunity to monitor CPU, MEM and Disk load in time, on Windows side I use `NSClient++` to connect to `Nagios` server

1. For CPU I use `check_nt_cpuload`, this is a `Nagios` plugin,
2. For memory I use `check_memory`
3. I'm using `SNMP` for checking free disk space, also for checking used memory by a single process, I'm also using `SNMP` for checking how much a process is taking from CPU.
   Also I have setup `Nagios` to send emails when a trash-hold is reached (e.g., Memory on server 1 is critical).

It took me about 5 days to have it working and now I have logs for about 10 mounts and I can tell how much server was loaded in a specific period of time