# Is possible to monitor instant CPU usage in windows7 over SNMP?

Tags: windows-7, snmp, oid

I am trying to monitor CPU load. After reading this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/113842/monitor-a-windows-server-using-snmp), I have found an OID  that allows me to check average use over **last** minute:

> **.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.1**
>
> {iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) host(25) hrDevice(3) hrProcessorTable(3) hrProcessorEntry(1) hrProcessorLoad(2)}

But I am interested in monitoring **instant** CPU load.
Is it possible? If so, how?

What I have tried so far:

- I have found this [OID](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1.2.1) (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1.2.1). Not sure if it will work because it seems for Windows NT. Not sure if it should work in windows 7. I am investigating now...

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result? It seems to me that would have been faster than typing the question.

Comment: I didn't explained well. I've already tried and is not working in windows 7. I was wondering if 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.* where only for "NT" windows (Either just windows NT or also Windows 2000, 2003, 2008). What I wanted to say is that I was going to try harder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the standard Windows SNMP agent doesn't report real-time data, you'll have to create your own agent or find one that does.

Comment: SNMP reports instantly. My problem is that OID is for **CPU average during last minute** and I want **instant CPU load**, the load that cpu has in every moment...

Comment: Right, I understand. Like I said, if your current Windows agent does it for a minute, then you'll have to find one that does or write your own.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. If instead of default Windows Agent I install another (say Nagios) then it might return something in 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.*