# Do you know any SNMP agent for windows that allows to monitor instant load of CPU?

Tags: snmp

In this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/421159/is-possible-to-monitor-instant-cpu-usage-in-windows7-over-snmp) I asked about the possibility of monitoring instant cpu load.

The answer was that windows default snmp agent does not give that option (seems only allow to read **1 minute average cpu load**).

After googling for it there is no clear indication if other agents give **average cpu load** or **instant cpu load** so my plan is to install several until  I learn if they provide **instant cpu load** or not.

**QUESTION**

> So, anyone knowns or have used a windows (even a linux will be
>   acceptable) SNMP Agent software that provide **instant cpu load**?

It will be a really time saver to know which one to try instead of choosing it blidnly.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this and it does support it, not sure if it is builtin or it is a custom field, as it was a couple of years ago in a different company.

http://www.snmp-informant.com/

it has 30 day free trial.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as instant load, a cpu core only does one thing at a time. CPU usage is always an average.  How small that average needs to be depends on what you are trying to monitor. But for example if you are monitoring cpu usage over hours or days how is it useful to have a smaller average than 1min?

Comment: What I meant by **instant load** is the same kind of CPU usage info that windows task manager gives you. I suppose interval is 1 sec or 5 secs... not sure.